# Microsoft Graph: Can get Refresh Token when having Access Token?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have an application integrated with O365 via SSO.
I wrote an Add-In for it that operates on Graph. When a user logs in, Add-In receives their access token to act on their behalf. I need a "Refresh Token" to act on behalf of the user even when the user is not logged in.

Can I request a "Refresh Token" in an independent inquiry for later use by receiving an "Access Token"?

Comment: Let me explain how token works. When a client acquires an access token to access a protected resource, the client also receives a refresh token. The refresh token is used to obtain new access/refresh token pairs when the current access token expires. A refresh token is bound to a combination of user and client. A refresh token can be revoked at any time, and the token's validity is checked every time the token is used. Refresh tokens are not revoked when used to fetch new access tokens - it's best practice, however, to securely delete the old token when getting a new one.

Comment: Does it helped?

Comment: But the refresh token is not generated automatically. I have to ask for it from AD via the offline_access option. In my case, the authorization proces is beyond me.
In summary: I can't got refresh token after autorization, even with the access token. Truth?